# jQuery Display div relative to another div when specific radio button value selected

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, css-position

So I have my blog set up to pull posts from my database in a loop. Each post (#post_) is coupled with a pair of radio buttons. When a radio button is selected, ajax sends the value to check.php where the values are put in my database. The returned html is then displayed in #Message_.

I want to make it so that ONLY when the Like radio button is selected, the div (#Message_) will appear OVER the top right corner of that post's div.

This is the code I currently have which displays the #Message when any radio button is selected but displays it only underneath the #post.

Calling the loop:

```
<div id="content">

<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
        <legend>Posts</legend>

<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
?>
```

The jQuery itself, sitting inside the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name*='pref_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>']").click(function() {
        var postID = <?php echo $row['postID']; ?>;
        var value = $(this).val();
        var userID = <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'userID=' + userID + '&postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').html('').html(result);
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Display the posts inside the loop:

```
<div id="post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" class="post">
<div id="post_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>_inside">
    <b><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></b><br>
    Expires: <?php echo $row['Exp']; ?><br>
    <ul id="listM"></ul>

    <form id="form_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" action="/">  
        <fieldset> 
            <div class="left"><p><input id="like_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" type="radio" name="pref_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" value="1"<?php if ($checked['value'] == "1") echo " checked"; ?> />
            <label for="like_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>">Like</label></p></div>
            <div class="right"><p><input id="dislike_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" type="radio" name="pref_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>" value="0"<? if ($checked['value'] == "0") echo " checked"; ?> />
            <label for="dislike_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>">Dislike</label></p></div>
                <hr />
        </fieldset>  
    </form>  
</div>
</div>
<div id="Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>"></div>
```

End the loop:

```
<?php 
} 
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but you can figure out what I've done here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name*='pref_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>']").click(function() {
        var postID = <?php echo $row['postID']; ?>;
        var value = $(this).val();
        var likeDislike = $(this).id().toString().replace(/(.*)_(.*)/,'$1'); //get 'like or dislike'
        var userID = <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'userID=' + userID + '&postID=' + postID + '&value=' + value,
            success: function(result) {
                if (likeDislike == 'like') { 
                    //do like stuff
                    //move the message element into the post at the top, use CSS like float:right or text-align:right etc. to position it to the right
                    $('#Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').prependTo('#'+postID);
                }
                else if (likeDislike == 'dislike') { 
                    //do dislike stuff
                    $('#Message_<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>').html('').html(result);
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, I see how this would display the message only if dislike is selected... but how about the positioning relative to the post div? That's the crux of my problem...

Comment: ok I've updated my answer, im using jQuery's `.prepend()` to move the message element to the top of the post element. you can use CSS to position it where you wish.

Comment: I have another question that maybe you can answer:
When I remove the fieldset tags, my checkboxes and radio buttons don't work anymore. Do you know why? How can I get it to work without fieldset?

Comment: clicking the buttons doesn't work when the fieldset tags are removed. You can click forever but the buttons will never set to checked and because of that, none of the jQuery executes.

Comment: hmmm.. i say post another question so more people can look at it.